# Datum object in caffe - unsupervised networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, unsupervised-learning

from a script on preparing data for a caffe network, the following piece of code turns an image (numpy array representing an image) into a datum object.

```
datum = caffe_pb2.Datum(
        channels=3,
        width=224,
        height=224,
        label=label,
        data=np.rollaxis(img, 2).tostring())
```

**If the network were unsupervised, do you just create the object the same way but do not fill the label parameter, as shown below?**

```
datum = caffe_pb2.Datum(
            channels=3,
            width=224,
            height=224,
            data=np.rollaxis(img, 2).tostring())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `label` of `Datum` is [`optional`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L36):

> ```
> optional int32 label = 5;
> ```

Meaning oyu do not have to provide it.

Side note:
`Datum` is a data structure used mainly for `"Data"` input layer and strictly speaking it is not part of the trained net.
Caffe uses N-D tensors [`Blobs`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L10-L22) to store both data and parameters of the net.

Comment: Shai, I wonder if you can take a stab at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942883/bekeley-caffe-command-line-interface